# pytest modules using os.environ - How do I test it correctly?

Tags: python, environment-variables, pytest, monkeypatching

currently I am writing some Webapp, but this time I want to learn how to write proper tests for it (using pytest) :)

A very common pattern I often see is to make the default configuration changeable using environment variables.
Currently I am struggling how to test this properly.

I've prepared some demo:

```
./app
./app/conf.py
./conftest.py
./run.py
./tests
./tests/test_demo.py
```

My `./app/conf.py` looks like this:

```
from os import environ

DEMO = environ.get('DEMO', 'demo')
TEST = environ.get('TEST', 'test')
```

Launching the `./run.py` shows that the settings are indeed changeable:

```
from os import environ

environ['DEMO'] = 'not a demo'
environ['TEST'] = 'untested'

from app import conf

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(conf.DEMO)
    print(conf.TEST)
```

It prints out `not a demo` and `untested` - as expected. Great. (Note that I set the environment variables before importing `conf`).

Now to the tests: The `./conftest.py` is currently empty it just helps pytest to locate the modules inside the app folder.

The `./tests/test_demo.py` contains the following:

```
def test_conf_defaults():
    from app import conf

    assert conf.DEMO == 'demo'
    assert conf.TEST == 'test'


def test_conf_changed(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('DEMO', 'tested demo')
    monkeypatch.setenv('TEST', 'demo test')

    from app import conf

    assert conf.DEMO == 'tested demo'
    assert conf.TEST == 'demo test'

    monkeypatch.undo()
```

If I run pytest now, `test_conf_changed` fails with `'demo' == 'tested demo'` -> the monkeypatch function did not patch the environment.

If I swap both testing functions (so `test_conf_changed` runs first), the `test_conf_defaults` will fail with `'tested demo' == 'demo'`.

How I interpret it, is - the first time `conf` gets imported it sticks there with it's initial settings..

How can I tell pytest to completely reimport `conf` each test function, *after* setting up the environment variables?

I am stuck there for two days now - and slowly I doubt if testing is worth the hassle - please prove me wrong :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve: if you want to run tests, you run `py.test` and it'll pick up all `test_*.py` files and run tests within those. If you want to have a demo, you'd create a file like `./demos/demo.py` and run that as demonstration. I don't think either of them (certainly not pytest) should depend on environment variables.

Comment: And yes, when you import `conf`, and variables inside the conf module are set inside the global namespace, they stick around: one import only during a whole run (python session). If you want to keep reading or setting env. variables, create a function in conf.py, like `updateenv()`, and run that each time you need from within your other functions to update the env variables.

Comment: What I want to achieve: The config.py holds default settings, but I want to make them changeable. e.g. the Path where to store temporary files, etc.

Comment: Now I want to test, if the assignment works correctly - the demo I wrote is just for stackoverflow - it has nothing to do with my real Application - It just shows the basic principles.

Comment: Of course pytest should be independent from environment variables. I want pytest to set some variables (locally) and then test my code (in conf.py) if it behaves correctly using this variables...

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for the hint, Evert (*variables inside the conf module are set inside the global namespace, they stick around*) - I think I got it now.

To test my code I have to explicitly reimport `conf` after setting the environment variables. Changing the code in `./tests/test_demo.py` to this does the trick:

```
from importlib import reload

from app import conf


def test_conf_changed(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('DEMO', 'tested demo')
    monkeypatch.setenv('TEST', 'demo test')

    reload(conf)

    assert conf.DEMO == 'tested demo'
    assert conf.TEST == 'demo test'


def test_conf_defaults():

    reload(conf)

    assert conf.DEMO == 'demo'
    assert conf.TEST == 'test'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a variation of the same issue while using *pytest* and *importlib* to validate imports.  The imported modules have the option to override certain settings with environment variables.  After patching the environment variable with *monkeypatch*, it is necessary to call *importlib.reload* against the imported module object in order for the patched variables to be evaluated since they were originally evaluated before the *monkeypatch*.

Adding this variation of spky's answer with an *importlib* example to increase the answer scope to cover cases for those working with *importlib*.

```
import importlib

def test_env_override(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('APP_ROOT', '/tmp')
    _temp = importlib.import_module('appconfig', 'APP_ROOT')
    importlib.reload(_temp)
    assert getattr(_temp, 'APP_ROOT') == '/tmp'
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29823312)